# handlebar: TypeError: (depth0 || container.hooks.helperMissing).call is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Even though the question is already asked it dont provide any solutions I am using handlebar as a templating engine for node+express.

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let userLog=req.session.userLog
  productHelper.getAllProduct().then((products) => {
    // console.log(products)
    res.render('user/user-view-products', { userLog,products})
  })
```

the products and userLog contains the necessary data.

I am using a header to be injected as a partial in handlebar. If just products is passsed  the  page loads ,but when userLog is passed the error message is shown.

```
 {{#if userLog}}
        {{this. name_field}}
        {{else}}
        Account
        {{/if}}
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
         {{#if userLog}}
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/login">Logout</a>

      {{else}}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/login">Login</a>
     {{/if}}
```

this is  the code that cause the problem. after it for quite a while

Comment: Why do you have a space between `this.` and `name_field`?

Comment: that was it . the space never caught my eye